# Ruby "is" equivalent

Tags: python, ruby

Is there a Ruby equivalent for Python's "is"? It tests whether two objects are identical (i.e. have the same memory location).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `a.equal? b`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html

> Unlike ==, the equal? method should never be overridden by subclasses: it is used to determine object identity (that is, a.equal?(b) iff a is the same object as b).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `__id__`. This gives you the objects internal ID number, which is always unique. To check if to objects are the same, try

> `a.__id__ = b.__id__`

This is how Ruby's standard library does it as far as I can tell (see `group_by` and others).